# php mongo aggregate project to date field

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In php I have the following mongo aggregate funnction:

```
array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            "i" =>  array('$in' => $valRefId),
            "date" => array('$gt'=> $mongotimestart , '$lte'=> $mongotimeend),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "i" => '$i',
            "v" => '$v',
            "datumpje" => array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date)),
            "year" => array('$year' =>array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
            "month" => array('$month'=>array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
            "day" => array('$dayOfMonth'=>array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
            "hour" => array('$hour'=> array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                "valRefId" => '$i',
                "year" => '$year',
                "month" => '$month',
                "day" => '$day',
                "hour" => '$hour',
            ),
            "MaxValue" => array('$max' => '$v'),
            "MinValue" => array('$min' => '$v'),
            "Gemiddelde" => array('$avg' => '$v'),
            "Aantal" => array('$sum' => 1),
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            "_id.valRefId" => 1,
            "_id.year" => 1,
            "_id.month" => 1,
            "_id.day" => 1,
            "_id.hour" => 1,
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "date" => array(
                '$concat' => array(array('$substr' => array('$_id.year',0,4)),
                    "-",
                    array('$substr' => array('$_id.month',0,2)),
                    "-",
                    array('$substr' => array('$_id.day',0,2)),
                    " ",
                    array('$substr' => array('$_id.hour',0,2)),
                    ":00:00",
                ),
            ),
            "MaxValue" => '$MaxValue',
            "MinValue" => '$MinValue',
            "Gemiddelde" => '$Gemiddelde',
            "Aantal" => '$Aantal',
        )
    ),
);
```

The meaning of the function is get the maxValue, MinValue, Average and number of records in a time window where **`$i`** is in a given array (**`$valRefId`**) and then group by **`$i`**, **`$year`**,**`$month`**,**`$day`** and **`$hour`**.

As result I now have the "_id". "date", "maxValue", "minValue", "Gemiddelde", "Aantal".

My question is now, is it possible to return the "date" field not in string type, but as a Date type (or timestamp type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can return the date field in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator as follows:

```
$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            "i" =>  array('$in' => $valRefId),
            "date" => array('$gt'=> $mongotimestart , '$lte'=> $mongotimeend),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "i" => 1,
            "v" => 1,
            "datumpje" => array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date)),
            "year" => array('$year' =>array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
            "month" => array('$month'=>array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
            "day" => array('$dayOfMonth'=>array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
            "hour" => array('$hour'=> array('$add'=>array('$date',$timezone_date))),
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                "valRefId" => '$i',
                "year" => '$year',
                "month" => '$month',
                "day" => '$day',
                "hour" => '$hour',
            ),
            "date" => array('$first' => '$datumpje'),
            "MaxValue" => array('$max' => '$v'),
            "MaxValue" => array('$max' => '$v'),
            "MinValue" => array('$min' => '$v'),
            "Gemiddelde" => array('$avg' => '$v'),
            "Aantal" => array('$sum' => 1),
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            "_id.valRefId" => 1,
            "_id.year" => 1,
            "_id.month" => 1,
            "_id.day" => 1,
            "_id.hour" => 1,
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I now get the first entry found in the group by function. 
I think I can work with this.

But it is possible to change the string type of the 'date' field to a date type?

Comment: There is no way to convert string to date in aggregation pipeline, however date to string is possible.